# How to handle https requests to a local http server

Tags: http, ssl, printing, https, odoo

We are implementing an application that uses ssl certificate (https), and the application could be used to send printing requests to intelligent printers on local network of the user, the problem is, our website uses http(s) and it sends http requests to the printers, but chrome blocks the request stating that we cannot send http requests from an https website, how to get around that ?

There is an option to enable ssl certificate, but i am not sure how will this identify a server/printer on the local network, because AFAIK ssl is tied to domains. does that i mean that i need a static ip for the printer ? if that's the case, how will i be able to send requests to the printer if the internet is down ?

I am wondering how Odoo solves this problem in their application, because they send requests to printers too.

Comment: Since when does Odoo send print requests to printers? IIRC there is a very nice community module doing that. That one is using CUPS to communicate with printers.

Comment: what i meant that Odoo has a POSBox that acts as a gateway between the browser and other hardware, so how does odoo in the browser (https) interact with the POSBox ?